# Formatting string output in Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-lex

I'm trying to print a series of objects in a List using the C# version of AWS Lambda. Its linked to my AWS RDS and my Lex bot. Currently, when I test the bot using the LEX test console, the output that is printed isn't formatted with line breaks even though I'm using the \n line break for C#.

Example Code:

```
        var result = string.Empty;

        result = $"Events for {User}:";
        foreach (var evt in events)
        {
            result += $"\n\n{evt.ID} - {evt.FeedbackType} - {evt.Status} - {evt.OpenedDate.ToString()}";
        }

        return result;
```

Below is the output I am getting on Lex:

[image: output]

Can anyone please explain how to fix this or if its an issue with the LEX Console? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is simply a limitation of the lex console. You are at the mercy of the program rendering the chat to handle formatting. Try integrating to Slack - you'll see it work there. The lex console is pretty basic.

BTW if it is of any use, I've got a little app to let you chat with your bot in the commandline. As long as you are logging into the AWS CLI: https://github.com/dwmkerr/lex-chat.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Slack integrated lex-bot new lines work as expected. Seems it is an issue of the simple bot console.