# How to make contentType dynamic in aws Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have been working on Lex project recently. My project require dynamic content in content type but I am not able to figure that out.

My current fulfillment is:

```
"I can help you with : 1. Book a hotel 2. Book a car. What would you like me to do?"
```

What I require is :

```
"I can help you with:
                           1. Book a hotel 
                           2. Book a car. 
                           What would you like me to do?"
```

I have tried with below code:

```
def HelpMsg(intent_request, intent_name):
    if intent_name == 'HelpMsg':
        response = {
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': 'Fulfilled',
            'message': {'contentType': 'Plaintext', 'content': 'I can help you with '
                                 '\n1. Book a hotel '
                                  '\n2. Book a car'
                                '\nWhat would you like me to do?'}

        }}
        return response
```

Let me know if this is possible to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering of the response depends on the client which you are using.
Lex console does not support new line.

FB Messenger will add new line using `\n`:

```
I can help you with : \n1. Book a hotel \n2. Book a car. \nWhat would you like me to do?
```

Website will add new line using `<br>`:

```
I can help you with : <br>1. Book a hotel <br>2. Book a car. <br>What would you like me to do?
```

You can add spacing as you like.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804682/formatting-string-output-in-amazon-lex) question for details.