# Null response from dialogAction(Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am getting null response while my code is successfully working. I am not able to get response from dialogAction, i am

```
import json
import requests

def getdata(intent_name, fulfillment_state, message):
  response = {

        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
  }
  return response


def lambda_handler(event,context):
 payload = {'userId':4,'type':'PARENT'}

 r = requests.post("http://ec2-54-226-57-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Tracking/rest/api", data=json.dumps(payload), headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'})
 print(r.content) 
 getdata(
        'currentIntent',
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'message'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your code should be:

```
import json
import requests

def getdata(message):
    return {
        'dialogAction':{
            'type':'Close',
            'fulfillmentState':'Fulfilled',
            'message':{
                'contentType':'PlainText',
                'content':message
            }
        }
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    payload = {'userId':4,'type':'PARENT'}
    r = requests.post("http://ec2-54-226-57-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/Tracking/rest/api", data=json.dumps(payload), headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'})
    print(r.content) 
    return getdata(r.content)
```

Let us know if you are getting any error.

Comment: great. last question how can i get value of slots that i have written in my lex. here i am not getting anything from my bot. let my intent is "coffee_intent" and have slots like "type."

Comment: that info is present in `event`. try to print/log it and see the attributes you are getting.

Comment: I am getting message successfully but not able to print it into 2 lines. How can i achieve this?

Comment: it depends on your client to render the output.

Comment: like i am getting response message as "hi, your order completed " i want it to print as "hi" in first line and remaining in second.

Comment: i have one more question if u can help.

Comment: if you're using fb messenger as client, then `\n` should work fine for line break.

Comment: No, i am not using FB messenger i am just using test console to check whether i am getting next line. And i just wanna use as simple chatbot not with fb messenger. In present case \n is not working. any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804682/formatting-string-output-in-amazon-lex this might be of help, also search a bit on StackoverFlow before asking, that will get you result faster.